# Should I add "use strict" to my meteor files?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In javascript development running your code in strict mode by adding:

```
"use strict";
```

To the beginning of your functions is a common best practice. However I have yet to see anyone do so in a meteor application.

Does this best practice not apply to Meteor?

Maybe because it sets strict mode on a higher level? I know that node can be run with the --use-strict command line parameter to enforce this. But I do not know of a way to do the same in the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using  `"use strict"` in Meteor is still a good practice - it is JavaScript after all.

Comment: Could you expand on this? For instance, should it be added to the top of every file, or is it possible to force `'use strict';` for all JavaScript source in a Meteor app?

Comment: Yes, it should be added to the top of every file where you want to have strict mode enabled.

Comment: Related feature request: [Enforce strict mode globally with meteor run --strict](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3510)

Answer (score 14):

There are two options that I know, if you want to `'use strict'` at the top of your Meteor files.

The first is to define a global variable like `APP` in one of your top Meteor files (and not in `strict` mode), then use it to namespace all of your previously global variables:

```
// first file
APP = {};

// later file
'use strict';

APP.Stuff = new Mongo.Collection('stuff');
APP.Stuff.find({});
```

The second method is to create a global alias in that first file:

```
// first file
G = this;

// second file
'use strict';

G.Stuff = new Mongo.Collection('stuff');
Stuff.find({});
```

The benefit of the latter is that you don't need to type `App.`- every time you want to use your "global" references—they still work as globals, and you only need to use `G.`- once—for your declarations.

Comment: I like it, what's your pattern for namespacing shared functions & global constants?

Comment: For globals, in that same file where I define G, I define `G.glob = {};`. Then in a client conditional, for instance: `if (Meteor.isClient) { G.glob.MY_CLIENT_GLOBAL = 'something'; }`. So we can have globals that are for the client, server, or shared. Similar objects could be constructed to house utility functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using harmony (es6) and you want to use global variable, you can use [export](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-harmony/blob/master/tests/harmony_test_setup.next.js#L3).

```
"use strict"
export var Book = new Mongo.Collection('book');
```