# Use Strict MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, strict

Accidental Duplicate:
[Should I add "use strict" to my meteor files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829837/should-i-add-use-strict-to-my-meteor-files)

From what I understand, `use strict` is good practice in JavaScript.

Should I use this when building MeteorJS Apps? If I should, where should I include this statement?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer **YES**

the its a good practice because MeteorJs at the end of the day is Javascript

> where should I include this statement?

At the very top of each file.

Also @pfkurtz on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829837/should-i-add-use-strict-to-my-meteor-files) gives 2 methods to use it, im never test that options, but the answer have up votes so it could work.

This [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380) its helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using strict mode is generally a very good habit that can save you plenty of trouble later on. To use it, just include this statement:

```
'use strict';
```

As first line of **every** .js file in your project.

Read more about why it's a good idea to use strict mode: "[It's time to start using JavaScript in strict mode](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/)", "[JavaScript's strict mode and why you should use it](http://cjihrig.com/blog/javascripts-strict-mode-and-why-you-should-use-it/)".