# How to properly import js files in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I like keeping my javascript files as small as possible and using an [architectural pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern). This usually means splitting my js files in Services, Controllers, Models, Views, etc.

Meteor automatically loads all js files. However every variable defined in any js file is processed as a local variable for that file. To be able to access them I have to define them like so:

```
//global
my_global_function = function(){

}

//not global
var my_global_function = function(){

}

//not global
function my_global_function(){

}
```

Defining a variable/function without the keyword `var` or `function` is not good practice. What are the possible alternatives?

Comment: As you state, by not including the 'var' keyword is how you declare that a variable should have global visibility.  This is simply the syntax as defined, and you do not seem confused about it.  So what do you believe is bad practice?  Having globals, or simply declaring them this way?  Certainly limiting your use of globals is a very good idea, but this is not relevant to syntax.  You could look into splitting your code into packages where externally visible variables must be explicitly declared.  It's an excellent  practice, but still not one I'd recommend just to declare globals differently.

Comment: That's right, you shouldn't declare them without `var` because that's causing confusion, way better would be `window.variable` or `global`variable` server side. I don't believe there is another way to share variables between files without some require() function or sth like that

Comment: If this is for `strict mode` compliance consider the approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829837/should-i-add-use-strict-to-my-meteor-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to use ES2015 modules.

Meteor does not support modules natively yet, but there are packages that bring this support.

For example, [universe:modules](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/modules).

With modules you can import and export some variables/functions/classes/etc:

```
// module1.import.js
import alertSomething from './module2'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  alertSomething();
});
```

```
// module2.import.js
export default function alertSomething() {
  alert('something');
}
```

---

`universe:modules` is not the only solution, there are other similar projects. I love this one specially https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart-simple. It replaces Meteor's build system with WebPack's and enables hot-reloading if you use React.

**UPDATE:**

Meteor does support ES6 modules now

Comment: This was actually exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem very interested in proper architectural design, I would recommend looking at Meteor packages. Essentially, you have to declare any globally exposed variable in the `package.js` configuration, which is what you want: as little "leakage" as possible. Within a package, you can afford to be a little bit more sloppy, but you can still use `var` (and the absence of `var`) for more fine-grained control within a package. This can be done within Meteor right now.

You can find most information in the [package documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs). The easiest way to get started is to create a package using `meteor create --package [package-name]`. This sets up a basic structure to play with. The `api.export` function is what controls exposed variables. See doc [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export).

Additionally, be careful with adding an unnecessary layer on top of the intrinsic Meteor architectural design. Templates **are** views, server side methods **are** services, etc. There are only some things that you don't get out of the box, so usually you'll add something like [Astronomy](http://astronomy.jagi.io/what-is-astronomy) or SimpleSchema.

Adding too much of your own architecture is probably going to end with you fighting the Meteor framework itself...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you expand on the package.js you mentioned?

Comment: I've added it inside my answer!