# Meteor "use strict" with global alias

Tags: meteor

In another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571757/5047454), the second option is to write `G.this;` in the first "top" file in order to create a namespace.
And then write "use strict" on the top of every other js file.

Is that all the content of such a file? and if so, where the "top" file should be located (server, client, both) and what name? as Meteor loads files based on their paths.   Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but yes, you can add `"use strict"` to the top of any file *where you want strict mode enabled*.

Comment: What the "top" file should be located? does it need to load before any other file? should it be in a folder and named with certain name so that Meteor opens it first? i.e. "top"?

Comment: Yes, the file where `G = this;` is declared should be loaded first, and preferably on both server and client. You could place it in a file called `app.js` at the root of your meteor application to have it loaded first and on both client and server.

Comment: I was looking at the docs and could not find app.js get the priority to load first. do you have a link? thx

Comment: My previous comment is not correct. I added an answer with the correct answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of ways to create a global namespace in Meteor (as suggested in the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571757/3507137)) is to have a file where a global alias to `this` is declared, such as:

```
G = this;
```

This file should, ideally, be **loaded first** and **on both client and server**.

To achieve this, according to the [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

1. Files within `lib/` directory are loaded first (after loading template files on client).
2. Meteor will load any file outside `client/` or `server/` directories on both client and server.
3. Where no other rules may apply, alphabetical ordering of the paths is used to determine load order of the files.

So, in keeping with these rules I would save the file as `app.js` (or any similar name that would come first alphabetically). Then I would place this file at the root of `lib/` folder so that it gets loaded both on client and server.

So, the path to `app.js` would be : `./your_meteor_project_root/lib/app.js`